# Is there a difference between $firstName and firstName in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

When I create a variable with jQuery which is firstName:

```
var $firstName = '';
```

or

```
var firstName = '';
```

Is there a difference between using '$' or not?

Comment: There is nothing to do with jquery here. Its a valid javascript variable name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$` in JavaScript variables doesn't mean anything in terms of functionality. It is typically just used on a variable that contains a jQuery object, for ease of readability.

For example, you might use it in this way:

```
var $firstName = $('input[name="first_name"]'); // storing a jQuery object
```

For something that isn't a jQuery object, such as a string, the `$` can be used but usually isn't:

```
var firstName = 'Sandeep';
```

You can freely name any variable with the `$` prefix, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use both of them as $ in variable name has nothing to do with jquery. As long as you have a valid javascript variable name, you can use $ before your variable name.

So for example :

```
var $firstName = "ABC";
```

and

```
var firstName = "ABC";
```

when called in console.info() will output same things :

```
console.info($firstName); // outputs "ABC" in firebug console.

console.info(firstName); // outputs "ABC" in firebug console.
```